# Как получить значение из строки в БД SQL?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Мне нужно вытащить значение из строки в БД и если значение в этой строке равно male то выполнить вывод текста в терминал,пытаюсь это сделать вот так

```
    def get_genderr(self, chat_id, gender):
    with self.connection:
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `chat_id`, 'gender' = (?,?)", (chat_id, gender)).fetchmany(1) # Просмотр пола
        if gender == 'male':
            print('тест')
```

Пишу на python база данных sql3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def select_gender_db(chat_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    gender = conn.execute('SELECT gender FROM users WHERE chat_id = ?', [chat_id]).fetchone()
    if gender is None:
        conn.close()
        return None
    else:
        conn.close()
        gender_id = gender[0]



a = select_gender_db(message.chat.id)
if a == 'male':
   print('male')
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот запрос который вам нужно совершить:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE chat_id = chat_id AND gender = gender
```

Нужно вместо этих двух переменных подставить значения.

Comment: все равно не получается